# background-image css not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

I'm building a simple site with bootstrap and I can't seem to get the background-image css styling to work. I want to put it on my .jumbotron div which is the first section of my website (besides the navbar, some would call it the hero section).

Here is my code, where did I go wrong?

```
.main-banner {
    background-image: url("../img/collection-of-classic-cars.jpg") no-repeat;
}

<section>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="main-banner"></div>
            <h1>Welcome!</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#name" role="button">Contact us</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

File Path:

`/img/collection-of-classic-cars.jpg`

Comment: Does the css live in the Same folder as the HTML? And is the HTML In the root folder?

Comment: Does the image load if you put it in the HTML as `img` tag?

Comment: You don't have content in the `div.main-banner `. Try to put some text there see if that does something. 0 width and height will never show the picture.

Comment: The css is in a separate, css folder. And the image loads if I put it in an img tag. I tried putting an h1 tag in the div.main-banner and it displayed.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the image URL should be [relative to the stylesheet](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#url) not the HTML you are serving. So most likely your image path is not correct. Other very common mistake is mismatch in the file name. *FOO.jpg* is not the same as *foo.jpg* in unix like systems.

Comment: he failed property, not path

Comment: This is what worked for me. I tried using "/" and "./". When I read you answer, I tried "../" and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use no-repeat in `background-image` property, it's can be used within background shorthand, so make it this way:

```
.main-banner {
  background-image: url("../img/collection-of-classic-cars.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/background-image/
http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/background-repeat/

Answer (score 1):

`<div class="main-banner"></div>` have no size...
http://jsfiddle.net/fnw39gco/1/

no repeat need to define as own css tag:

background-repeat:no-repeat

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp

Comment: Thanks all for the quick replies! Setting the width and height did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As vicodin stated, your CSS code is wrong. The `background-image` property will only accept a URL. The best way would be to use the `background` shorthand:

```
background: url("../img/collection-of-classic-cars.jpg") no-repeat;

/* Adding even more options */
background: #FFF url('img.jpg') center fixed no-repeat;

/* Which would be the same as */
background-color: #FFF;
background-image: url('img.jpg');
background-position: center;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after going through many SO(Stack Overflow) Questions and almost after many hours of searching it on the internet. I came up with this

It worked when I saw the error on the console and the path, it was showing, missing some part of it(path)

Path shown on the console:

```
file:///E:/dist/img/model-1.jpg
```

So, I just provided the missing part and it worked.